# Codeception, architecture Global and Suite Helpers / PHP

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I'm learning this amazing `Test Framework` (**Codeception**) I already wrote a bunch of test as exercise and all are passed correctly.

Obviously I came a cross a same questions regarding the architecture and the reusability of the tests and the best practice on how use the different Class to structure the tests.

**Cest and Cept:**

How I read on the documentation there are typology of tests `cept` and `cest`.
 I experimented both writing tests but still the quantity that I done did not understand me when is the best use of each of them. The only thing I read on the documentation is the reason that if your test is too long create a `Cest Class` is the best approach.

**Global helpers**

Going to create a `functional test` for my login form I structured it like so:

```
$I = new TestGuy($scenario);
$I->am('A member');
$I->wantTo('Login in the application');
$I->amOnPage('/');

$I->signIn(); // This custom method belongs to a helper

$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/home');
```

Review the `SignIn` method

```
    /**
     * Class TestHelper
     *
     * @package Codeception\Module
     */
 class TestHelper extends \Codeception\Module
 {

    /**
     * Sign In a user
     */
    public function signIn()
    {
        $email = 'test@test.com';
        $password = 'Hello123';
        $username = 'user3';

        // create a dummy account
        $this->haveAnAccount(compact('email','password','username'));

        $I = $this->getModule('Laravel4');
        $I->fillField('.navbar-collapse input[name="email"]',$email);
        $I->fillField('.navbar-collapse input[name="password"]',$password);
        $I->click('LOG IN');
    }
}
```

This test pass correctly.

Now If I want to use the `signIn()` Method in my `functional tests` is pretty straight forward just use it.

The issue is came when I had to create an `Acceptance` test with `Selenium` and it require the exactly the same process to get the user logged in and I need to reuse the exactly the same method that in this circumstance I cannot use for acceptance.

So witch is the best practice to share and make global this helpers?

Answer (score 1):

This helper is already 'global'.
Everything you need is to add this helper to needed suite config - acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled: [AcceptanceHelper, YourHelper]
```

and then do not forget to run

```
php codeception.phar build
```

Comment: Hm, I get "[Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]
  Module AcceptanceHelper could not be found and loaded" when i add "- AcceptanceHelper:" to my suite config.